# Does SVN upload only the difference of a changed file when committing?

Tags: svn

It seems to me that SVN is taking surprisingly long to upload binary files in which small changes have occurred.

I always imagined SVN would only upload the diff of a file relative to some revision when committing, instead of the entire content.

Does anyone know what the behavior is?

Comment: The question what exactly is the difference in binary form of your file?

Comment: locally differencing the file revisions i can see that only a few bytes have changes in a ~50MB file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is that always will be transferred only the deltas (binary or text) to the server which is calculated based on the contents of the pristine which are in your working copy. (see .svn folder). If it takes long you should check your network, cause this is often the root sources of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format of the committed file, a small change can provoke a total change of the structure, and the whole file might have to be uploaded on each commit.